# Show a div only once per visit / set cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to set an element so it's being shown only once per visit. It's a scroll down arrow on my homepage and so once the user gets it it won't be necessary to keep it anymore. So I don't want it to be shown while the user is surfing on my website however, when he visits it again in the future it's there again. I'm a newbie and can't quite solve it. 
My code:

```js
        setTimeout(function () {
          $('.scroll_down').show()
          }, 2000);
          var $element = $('.scroll_down'); // fade out / in on scroll 
            $(window).scroll(function() {
              if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $element.fadeOut(1000);
              }
        });
```

I also would like the arrow to fade in but my attempts were not successful. Thanks guys

Comment: where is code for cookie?

Comment: I think the appropriate tool would be [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Hi, no code for cookie since I don't know how to insert it

Answer (score 2):

Please write cookie code as follow:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if($.cookie('show_div_once') != 'yes'){
    your_code_for_show_div;
}
$.cookie('show_div_once', 'yes', { path: '/', expires: 365 });
});
```

Comment: I did, please see below

Answer (score 0):

I used localStorage

```
firstSiteLoad  = (function() {
  var checkSupport;
  checkSupport = function() {
    var e, error, support;
    try {
      support = 'localStorage' in window && (window['localStorage'] != null);
    } catch (error) {
      e = error;
      support = false;
    }
    return support;
  };
  return function() {
    if (!checkSupport()) {
      return false;
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("not_first_load")) {
      return false;
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("not_first_load", 'true');
      return true;
    }
  };
})();
```

you can use it by `if (firstSiteLoad()) { //your code }`